# How to embed video FROM Google Plus?

Tags: video, embed, google-plus

It gives me to "Copy embed HTML" code:

```
<object style="height: 390px; width: 640px"><param name="movie" 

value="https://www.youtube.com/v/picasacid?version=3"><param 

name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" 

value="always"><embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/picasacid?version=3" 

type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" 

allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390"></object>
```

but when I put it on my blog it says "Movie not loaded...".

Comment: how are you getting this embed code?

Answer (score 6):

Google+ videos are stored as Picasa videos. They are served in a way that does not allow for easy embedding.

It would be easier for you to upload them to YouTube and embed using the YouTube code.

If you must use the Google+ version you can't use the player code in your Google+ feed because the video stream URL expires every 11 hours.

I did it in my website by periodically retrieving the video's RSS feed

```
https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/tiny/user/<<the video poster's userid>>/photoid/<<the video's id>>
```

and extracting the `<media:content url="<<video source url>>">`.
You can easily achieve this using the Google Picasa Api. I make an AJAX call to get the stream URLs on each user's visit but I have very few visitors.

You get a URL for each video format.

You use these URLs to replace the URLs from the embed code you can get from inspecting the Google+ player.

```
<embed width="800" height="600" flashvars="fs=1&amp;hl=en&amp;autoplay=1&amp;ps=picasaweb&amp;fmt_list=<<your fmt_list>>&amp;fmt_stream_map=<<your fmt_stream_map>>&amp;playerapiid=uniquePlayerId&amp;video_id=picasacid&amp;t=1&amp;vq=large&amp;auth_timeout=86400000000" wmode="opaque" scale="noScale" bgcolor="#fff" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="//www.youtube.com/get_player?enablejsapi=1&amp;vq=hd720">
```

The URLs are passed to the player in the embed's `flashvar` attribute. You need to replace the video formats list parameter: `fmt_list` and the stream URLs list : `fmt_stream_map`.

Keep in mind that the contents of the flashvar attributes are urlencoded and the contents of the `fmt_list` and `fmt_stream_map`, which you send inside the `flashvar` attribute, are also urlencoded so the `fmt_list` and `fmt_stream_map` end up doubly urlencoded.

I hope I was explicit enough.

Comment: Google changed the way this works. You can now use the media urls in a video tag. The URLs still expire though. You can get the URL the same way <media:content height="1080" medium="video" type="video/mpeg4" url="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/randomstuff=m37" width="1920"/> and use it in a video tag <video src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/randomstuff=m37" />

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell the player which video to load before it does. The urls in the embed code above point to the player, not the video.

Comment: I can see that this was your first answer to a question, so you didn't have the rep to post this as a comment, but in the future, you might want to consider posting this as a comment. Answers are supposed to be a solution to the problem that you are pretty confident will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract the HTML directly from the google plus page of the video, inspecting the DOM of the page that shows the video.

I don't understand if it is allowed to post links, but i'll try. This is a page of my blog which describes how I did it.
http://www.nicassio.it/daniele/blog/?p=27

Anyway, it's a kind of hack, it seems Google doesn't want us to share those videos outside G+.